# HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc, controller

I have the following controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/query")
public class QueryController {

    @Autowired
    private QueryService queryService;

    // this post API works perfectly fine
    @PostMapping(value = "/submit")
    public void submitQuery(@Valid @RequestBody Query query) {
        queryService.submit(query);
    }

    // this API is throwing the error
    @GetMapping(value = "/find/email/{email:.+}")
    public List<Query> fetchByEmail(@PathVariable("email") String email) {
        return queryService.fetchByEmail(email);
    }
}
```

I am sending the the following cURL request:

> curl -X GET http://localhost:8562/query/find/email/abc@gmail.com -H 'Content-Type: application/json'

In the debug mode, I can see the request has arrived at the controller with the expected emailId that I have sent in the request. The DAO layer search has also happened and it has returned 1 record, but the API throws the following error:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1569655451392,
    "status": 406,
    "error": "Not Acceptable",
    "message": "Could not find acceptable representation",
    "path": "/query/find/email/abc@gmail.com"
}
```

Can someone please help?

**Note: I am using springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'**

**Edit:** The GET API is the one that is throwing the error. Any request that does not have the dot character (.) works fine. The following request does not throw any error:

> curl -X GET http://localhost:8562/query/find/email/abc@gmail -H 'Content-Type: application/json'

**Edit-2:** Attaching the debug screenshot below:

[image]

From this point, if I run the code, I get the following error:

> {"timestamp":1569657676774,"status":406,"error":"Not Acceptable","message":"Could not find acceptable representation","path":"/query/find/email/rishi2893@gmail.com"}

Comment: Add media type in Post request.

Comment: Please add Query class. Your code should work perfectly.

Comment: @Sambit: I have an issue with the other API, the GET Api and not the POST Api

Comment: @i.bondarenko: Why do you even need to see the Query class? Please refer to the screenshot attached in Edit-2

Comment: Because I recreated your controller and it works fine:
`$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/query/find/email/abc@gmail.com -H 'Content-Type: application/json'`
Respose  code 200
`[{"name":"Kenny"}]`

The error can be caused by absence or broken getters.

Comment: @i.bondarenko: What do you have to say about the fact that in debug mode I am seeing the expected result but the API response is giving an error? Do you have any explanation for that? I have another API `/query/find/phone/{phone}` which works perfectly fine.

Comment: Sorry I can't reproduce this error locally. No idea yet.

Comment: When I created a user without a dot character in the email, and called the find by email API, it returned a correct response:`[{"name":"ronnie","email":"ronnie","phone":"8182","college":"UCSB","degree":"MSc","text":"fee structure?"}]` This should remove doubts regarding any Getter Setter issue, right?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 406 Not-Acceptable means that the server cannot produce a response in a format that the client can understand.

You have to send the `Accept` header so as to notify the server for the acceptable formats that your client can understand and to `ensure that your server can produce such formats`.

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" ...
```

In addition to the above, when the Content-Type header is sent in a request, it specifies the media type of the request being sent from the *client*. A Content-Type header should be used in POST/PUT requests. It does not make sense in a GET request as you should not have a body in such requests.

Comment: `curl -X GET http://localhost:8562/query/find/email/abc@gmail.com -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json'` throws the same error

Comment: On adding `produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }`, the request is not even going inside the Controller. It is throwing the same error even before reaching the Controller.

Comment: I just saw the issue with the dot. I suppose that this happens due to considering anything after the last dot as an extension. Maybe you could try to set the `useDefaultSuffixPattern` as false.

Comment: Does not work!! why are you even suggesting this? Look at my edit2 screenshot, email is getting correctly set, the DAO layer is also giving back the correct response.

Comment: As I suggested previously, the `produces` is used to specify the MIME types or representations that a resource can produce and send to the client. The fact that when adding it you have an issue, seems to me that your resource is not able to produce the specified MIME type. How is serialization done in your case? Are you using any dependencies?

Comment: `A Content-Type header should be used in POST/PUT requests. It does not make sense in a GET request` --Agreed!! but that does not solve my problem.

Comment: @User_Targaryen We're trying to help and pointing out issues with your approach.

Comment: @User_Targaryen check if this helps you https://blog.georgovassilis.com/2015/10/29/spring-mvc-rest-controller-says-406-when-emails-are-part-url-path/

Comment: Did not help. After doing the above, every GET request is throwing 406 error